# GPUs attached to google cloud instance no longer findable

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-compute-engine

I've been using google cloud platform without any issues for the past few months. 
However, I've run into a rather confusing issue. I have a gpu attached, which we use for our deep learning models. For some reason, this GPU is no longer showing up on the instance.

When I run

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 963983047914027708, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 11201145405798739252
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"]
```

The output I get suggests that there are no GPUs available. When I try and train a model, it's clear that it is not using the GPU due to dramatically decreased speed of training.

The only recent change I made was installing miniconda and creating a new conda env for a different project; is there some way that this could have interfered with the ability of my current code to recognize the GPU?

During creation of the conda env, I ran into a number of issues with the current cuda drivers and cuda version, but all of this took place within a dedicated conda env, so I don't see how I could have messed something up that would prevent recognition of the GPU.

Thanks in advance, 
Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that the default version of tensorflow had been updated in the docker file we were using. The new version was the CPU version, which by default doesn't ever look for GPUs

Answer (score 0):

When using GPUs, you need to take into account that there are some [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions), so I would recommend you to read through them and try to determine if any restriction has affected your particular case. As far as I know, installing new libraries doesn't have any impact on your code being incapable of recognising the GPUs. If you want to restore them, however, you can refer to this [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#add-gpu-to-instance).